Postgres CTE value not being used in where clause
I'm trying to run this query that updates an ordering column after inserting the rows, and everything seems to work fine except using the id FROM the CTE query in the WHERE clause doesn't work, even though it works everywhere else. This is the query
WITH variant AS (
    INSERT INTO accessory_variants (
        accessory_id,
        label,
        multiple
    ) VALUES (
        1,
        'Colors',
        FALSE
    ) RETURNING *
),
opts AS (
    INSERT INTO accessory_variant_options (
        accessory_id,
        accessory_variant_id,
        price,
        label,
        description
    ) VALUES (
        1,
        (SELECT id FROM variant),
        100,
        'Red',
        'A red one'
    ),
    (
        1,
        (SELECT id FROM variant),
        100,
        'Blue',
        'A blue one'
    ) RETURNING id
),
ids AS (
    SELECT JSONB_AGG(id) AS option_ids FROM opts
)
UPDATE
    accessory_variants
SET
    ordering = ids.option_ids
FROM
    variant,
    ids
WHERE
    accessory_variants.id = variant.id

Where it gets weird is if I change it to something like this
...
UPDATE
    accessory_variants
SET
    ordering = TO_JSONB(variant.id)
FROM
    variant,
    ids
WHERE
    accessory_variants.id = {existing row id}

The ordering table is populated with the correct id, so variant.id contains the correct id, but still can't be found by the where clause

Reading more I see why this isn't working

The primary query and the WITH queries are all (notionally) executed at the same time. This implies that the effects of a data-modifying statement in WITH cannot be seen from other parts of the query, other than by reading its RETURNING output. If two such data-modifying statements attempt to modify the same row, the results are unspecified.

